# Unable to start embedded container; Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

i have a spring boot project. 
i use java 1.8
spring boot 1.4.7

when i try to run it i get following errors:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 10 common frames omitted


2018-02-24 11:53:26.120 ERROR 6540 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:552) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at co.abrtech.ezpay.services.projectName.config.Application.null(Unknown Source) [classes/:na]
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
       Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]


org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at co.abrtech.ezpay.services.projectName.config.Application.null(Unknown Source) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:552) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

and my pom.xml is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>co.abrtech.ezpay.services</groupId>
<artifactId>projectName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>co.abrtech.ezpay.services.projectName.config.Application</start-class>
    <swagger.version>2.6.0</swagger.version>
    <cxf.version>3.1.10</cxf.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Camden.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    <purchase.version>1.1.89</purchase.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-s3-release-repo</id>
        <name>S3 Release Repository</name>
        <url>s3://abr-thumbtack/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-s3-snapshot-repo</id>
        <name>S3 Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>s3://abr-thumbtack/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>cfd20fea7ca8-releases</name>
        <url>http://srv-it-linux.sohato.com:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>cfd20fea7ca8-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://srv-it-linux.sohato.com:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- start of swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of swagger -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>8.18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.abrtech.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>purchase</artifactId>
        <version>${purchase.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>-->
    <!--<groupId>org.stagemonitor</groupId>-->
    <!--<artifactId>stagemonitor-web</artifactId>-->
    <!--<version>0.31.0</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.stagemonitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>stagemonitor-web-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>0.86.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.stagemonitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>stagemonitor-logging</artifactId>
        <version>0.86.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.stagemonitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>stagemonitor-os</artifactId>
        <version>0.86.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.stagemonitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>stagemonitor-alerting</artifactId>
        <version>0.86.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.uadetector</groupId>
        <artifactId>uadetector-resources</artifactId>
        <version>2014.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ir.tosansoha.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
                <profiles>
                    <profile>soha</profile>
                </profiles>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProperties>
                            <encoding.source>UTF-8</encoding.source>
                            <encoding.reporting>UTF-8</encoding.reporting>
                            <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                            <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
                            <spring.boot-version>${parent.version}</spring.boot-version>
                            <spring.cloud-version>${spring-cloud.version}</spring.cloud-version>
                            <purchase.version>${purchase.version}</purchase.version>
                        </additionalProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::querydsl -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::querydsl -->

        <!-- tag::liquibase -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>LATEST</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ir.tosansoha.shared</groupId>
                    <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
                    <version>0.0.3</version>
                </dependency>


            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::liquibase -->

        <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <!--<wsdlOption>-->
                                <!--<wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/v1.xml</wsdl>-->
                                <!--<wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/v1.xml</wsdlLocation>-->
                            <!--</wsdlOption>-->
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

more detail can be add if needed.
any body have idea?

thanks for help!

---

update:

problem solved!!

it was a new git project that was not pushed. 
i pushed it and clone it in a new path . problem is solved. i don't know what was wrong!

Comment: can you post all error log?

Comment: it's edited now

Comment: is this full error log?

Comment: You should post full content of `pom.xml`, it is missing the top part, I don't see packaging option for artifact.

Comment: full error log and full pom added

Answer (score 1):

The method getVirtualServerName has been added in ServletContext in Servlet 3.1.
Check all your Maven dependencies and make sure that you are not pulling in a pre-3.1 version of the javax.servlet / servlet-api that may be taking precedence over what's in your Tomcat 8.

Comment: so it might not be because of my classes content?

Comment: i search in all dependencies. there is only one servlet-api with version 3.1

Comment: Yes, it might not be due to your classes. 
Check with dependency tree.